# How is the numpy.where() different from boolean array indexing?

Tags: python, numpy, logical-operators

What functionality does the numpy.where() accomplish which boolean indexing using numpy cannot? I can't see why one would be used versus another in a given situation.

Comment: `np.nonzero` (alias `np.where`) identifies the nonzero (`True`) elements of the index.  Timings suggest that `arr[bool_idx]` is actually evaluated as `arr[np.nonzero(bool_idx)]`.  So often both work.  If you already have the boolean mask, use it.